# How to execute a stored procedure in node js+firebird

Tags: node.js, firebird

I'm using node.js 6.9.0 and "[firebird](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebird)": "^0.1.3" connecting to a firebird 3. Currently, I have several queries that are working perfectly just calling in the form '`select * from ...`' then I decided to create a stored procedure and I'm having 2 problems.

1. The connexion.query is no longer an `FBResult object`(thenFunc) to apply the fetch that was giving me an error,
2. When I don't treat the result as an FBResult because is already a JSON string the received values are always null, However, I receive the correct column names.

The initial call was like this:

```
var sql = "EXECUTE PROCEDURE PRESENCE_GETTOTAL;"
var resultVec = [];
connexion.query(sql , function (err,rs){
          if( rs == null && err != null ){
            return reject(err);
          }
          else{
              console.log(rs);
            rs.fetch('all',true,function (rs){
              ShopDayString.push(rs);
            }, function (err, oef){
              if(oef) resolve(ShopDayString);
              if(err) reject(err);
            });
```

Then I realized it was giving back in `rs` the result as a JSON so I change it this way:

```
var sql = "EXECUTE PROCEDURE PRESENCE_GETTOTAL;"
    var resultVec = [];

    console.log(sql)

    connexion.query(sql , function (err,rs){
      if ( rs == null && err != null ){
        return reject(err);
      }
      else{
        console.log(rs);
        resultVec.push(rs);
        resolve(resultVec)
      }
    });
```

The problem now is that the values are always null, I run the exact same command in the isql-fb client and I got results. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: A potential workaround could be to make the stored procedure selectable (add `suspend` after producing the values), and execute with `select * from PRESENCE_GETTOTAL()`.

Comment: tried Henri's firebird-node library ?

Comment: @Arioch'The 1)Firebird new wire protocol is not supported and 2) I will have to re-engineer the full backend because I'm using a connection pool so all the queries pass through the same point.

Comment: No, a selectable stored procedure can return multiple rows, when using `execute procedure` you can only get one row.

Comment: Perhaps I should had posted that comment, in retrospect.... Firebird commands like `execute procedure` and `insert .. returning` do NOT return any rows, they return parameters/fields. They are not tabular! They receive and return set of scalar values. Read FB docs about selectable and not selectable procedures, if you need many rows per single command call (albeit Mark already told in top comment what needs to be done for multiple rows, however laconic it was)

Comment: I changed as @MarkRotteveel told me and it is working now!

Comment: Happy to hear the workaround works. I suggest that you create an issue at https://github.com/xdenser/node-firebird-libfbclient that either support for executable stored procedures needs to be fixed or - if it already works - needs to be documented.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel following your advise to report the issue, I found the correct way to call the procedure

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to execute a stored procedure is like this:

```
  var stmt = connexion.prepareSync("EXECUTE PROCEDURE PRESENCE_GETTOTAL;")
    var res = stmt.execSync();
    if(res){
      resolve(res);
    }
    else{
      res.fetch('all',true,function (rs){
        resultVec.push(rs);
      }, function (err, oef){
        if(oef) resolve(resultVec);
        if(err) reject(err);
      });
    }
```

So when we execute the Sync there is 2 option, If it is a single row it will immediately return the result. Otherwise, it will return **undefined** and you will have to fetch the results.
You can get more info in the [library repository](https://github.com/xdenser/node-firebird-libfbclient/issues/4)

**edit 1:** cleaner code suggested not using 'undefined'.

Comment: `if(undefined)` looks weird to me. Is that correct?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel this is exactly what the said in the github: "When statement returns set of rows (with select) - .execSync() will return undefined and results are to be fetched."

Comment: @aburbanol no, your original could was not following docs you quote,  `if ( constant-value ) ...` is just a way to remove code from program while keeping it in source, a quick way to comment/uncomment larger swaths of code. If JS `undefined` follows the concept of SQL `NULL` then any code wrapped within `if (undefined) {...}` is "dead code" that will never be executed.

Comment: And regardless, you have to make your mind which kind of SP and command you want to have. Either it should be a selectable SP called via `select` command and returning a tabular rowset, or it should be non-selectable SP called via `execute procedure` and returning single values and never rows. You can not have both, you should analyze you problem and decide which of those is proper way for you

Comment: With your edit, how can you perform `res.fetch` in the `else` branch of `if(res)`, given that means `res` is undefined, you should be able to invoke `fetch` on it.